# Как возможно в WordPress вывести значение атрибута ID в переменную?

Tags: html, wordpress, html5, вёрстка, cms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как возможно в WordPress вывести значение атрибута ID в переменную?

У меня есть страница и на ней через цикл сделал вывод одинаковых фрагментов кода, путем создания новых записей и применения им нужного шаблона и рубрики.

В каждом из этих фрагментов кода есть модальное окно, например, с **id="modalGallery-1** и есть блочок, по клику на котором это модальное окно отрывается, у него атрибут **data-target="#modalGallery-1**

Получается ID дублируется каждый раз при вставке нового фрагмента кода.
Пробовал через произвольные поля ACF сделать:

```
id="<?php the_field("modalGallery-1"); ?>"
data-target="#<?php the_field("modalGallery-1"); ?>"
```

Но так не работает почему-то, как возможно решить эту задачу? В таких случаях пользователю получается обязательно нужно предоставить доступ указать ID при редактировании записи, или можно как-то обойти это?

Comment: id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>"
data-target="#modalGallery-<?php  echo $post->ID;?>"

Comment: А покажите цикл, пор фовор?

Comment: Спасибо, Кирилл, я уже решил эту задачу)